# Variable in URL VB.net Telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to pass a variable in url like this:

```
<script language="VB" runat="server">
Dim id As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id")
Dim getEndpoint = "http://localhost:5000/equipments/" & id & "/moni"
</script>

<WebServiceDataSourceSettings>
<Select Url="<%=getEndpoint%>" RequestType="Get" />
</WebServiceDataSourceSettings>
```